# Можно ли и как задать функцию, которая будет вызывать сама себя

Tags: javascript

Сделал я вот такой код:

```
 const slide = document.getElementById('slider');
    const submit = document.getElementById('submit');
    submit.innerHTML = 'Создать поле' + slide.value + 'x' + slide.value;
    return slide.value;
};
getInputValue();
let h = 0;
const counter = () => h = !h;
const ticTacToe = function() {
    const buttonsArr = document.getElementById('buttonsDiv');
    buttonsArr.innerHTML = '';
    const slider = document.getElementById('slider');
    let innerFlex;
    for(let i = 0 ; i < slider.value * slider.value; i++) {
        if(i % slider.value == 0) {
            innerFlex = document.createElement('div');
            innerFlex.classList.add('flexChild');
            innerFlex.classList.add('flex');
            innerFlex.id = 'innerFlexId' + i;
            innerFlex.style.width = 50 * slider.value + 'px';
            innerFlex.style.height =     50 + 'px';
            buttonsArr.append(innerFlex);
            innerFlex = document.getElementById('innerFlexId' + i);
        }
        const btn = document.createElement('BUTTON');
        btn.class = 'flexChild';
        btn.style.width = 50 + 'px';
        btn.style.height = 50 + 'px';
        btn.onclick = function() {
            this.classList.add (counter() ? 'croses' : 'zeroes');
        };
        innerFlex.append(btn);
    }
    const buttonsArrChildList = buttonsArr.childNodes;
    const testFunc = function() {   
        if(this.line - 1 >= 0  || this.line - 1 >= 0) {
            buttonsArrChildList[this.line - 1].childNodes[this.order - 1].testFunc();
        }
    };
    for(let i = 0;i < buttonsArrChildList.length;i++) { 
        for(let j = 0; j < buttonsArrChildList[i].childNodes.length;j++) {
            const buttonExemple =  buttonsArrChildList[i].childNodes[j];
            buttonExemple.order = j;
            buttonExemple.line = i;
            buttonExemple.onclick = testFunc;
        }
    }
};
```

*Реально ли объявить функцию, в нашем случае testFunc, которая вызывает сама себя? как я понимаю у меня выдает ошибку из-за того, что я вызываю ее в момент когда она еще не объявлена*

Comment: Реально. Вызов функции в самой себе называется рекурсией.

Comment: @1ocke Извините, не могли бы вы тогда подсказать, где у меня ошибка в коде?

Answer (score 0):

```
const testFunc = function() {    
  if (this.line - 1 >= 0  || this.line - 1 >= 0) {
    testFunc.call(buttonsArrChildList[this.line - 1].childNodes[this.order - 1]);
  }
}
```

Покажите, как Вы вызываете `testFunc` в самый первый раз, что такое в ней `this`, и откуда берутся `line` и `order`.

Comment: добавил остальную часть кода

Comment: @LeoMotorBreath Молодец. Мой ответ - правильный.